# Debugging (breakpoints / etc) in VSCode with different makefiles for parts of the codebase

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile, cpputest

I'm working on an ESP-IDF based project that runs on ESP32 microcontrollers.

The project has a bunch of different C++ libraries (ESP-IDF calls them `components`) I've written. Normally I compile the whole project and it gets installed on the ESP32, and everything works great.

I've been writing tests, and how I make the tests work is a little different than the standard build process. For each set of tests, I am testing just one of my C++ components. (for instance "Wireless" or "UserInputs", etc) I mock out the rest of my components and the ESP-IDF code that my code uses, and this lets me just test "Wireless", for instance.

To do this, I'm using `CppUTest` and a series of makefiles. The makefile structure is based on the structure here: https://github.com/memfault/interrupt/tree/master/example/unit-testing/minimal

And here's the article I followed that is describing that makefile/testing setup.
https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/unit-testing-basics#setting-up-cpputest

So, there's a main makefile, and it finds all the per-component makefiles. Those per-component makefiles specify which `.cpp` files to compile, what folders to find your imports in, where your tests are, etc. And all that works great.

The situation I'm in is that I want to be able to run the debugger in VSCode to set breakpoints, pause execution, and inspect my variables at a given point in my code.

Just doing this in the tests is enough. I don't need debugger in my main ESP-IDF build process.

But I'm having the most challenging time working with this kind of setup. Because there's not just ONE make file.

Here's the core of what I want to do. I want to be able to set a breakpoint, and then do something to tell my code to compile with a given list of `.cpp` files, and header import locations. Just like in those per-component test make files. And I want my code to execute to that breakpoint and then give me the sauce in VSCode.

Any suggestions on how I can work in this direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work this out. Here's what I did...

Firstly, I ran my tests. Now when I look in `unit_tests/build/` I see sub
folders for each make file. And in those subfolders there are executables. For instance, `unit_tests/build/data/data_tests`

I made a `.vscode/launch.json` file in my repo. It's looks like this...

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch for Dispatch Component",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/unit_tests/build/dispatch/dispatch_tests",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch for Wireless Component",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/unit_tests/build/wireless/wireless_tests",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch for Data Component",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/unit_tests/build/data/data_tests",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

Notice that in that `launch.json` file there are multiple `configurations`. One for each component/make file. The `name` of each configuration says what component it's for, and the `program` field points to the executable that the tests built.

If I'm in the `Data` component and want to drop into a breakpoint, here's
what I do.

1. ensure that there's a test called by the `Makefile_data.mk` that hits my
   breakpoint.
2. click the `Run and Debug` button on the left in VSCode. (the bug with the play button)
3. click the dropdown at the top of `Run and Debug` and select `Launch for Data Component`
4. Hit play.

Now my tests run and when they get to the breakpoint in the code in my Data
component they will pause. Pretty slick!